# RequiredIf Not Firing Client Side Validation Styling

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, foolproof-validation

In my Model I have this:

```
[RequiredIf("Operation", 2)]
public string Test_Type { get; set; }
```

I am using [MVC Fool Proof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/).

In my view:

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Operation Type: <span class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></span></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Operation, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OperationChoice, "-- Select Operation --", new { @class = "form-control" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Operation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="TestType-div">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Type Of Test: <span class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></span></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Test_Type, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Test_TypeChoice, new {@class = "form-control"})
            <br/>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Test_Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This validation is working, but it does not highlight the `Test_Type` dropdownlist in a red outline with the css class `input-validation-error`.  How do I use the `RequiredIf` annotation in a way that when the form is invalid, it highlights the field with the `input-validation-error` class name?

Check This Code Online  [Codepen.io](http://kimechanic.com/1UFh)

Comment: Do you have a css style for `input-validation-error`?

Comment: yes, just to surround the element with a red outline

Comment: Could you show what the output is after razor is compiled? ... Also, including the relevant css used for styling the error would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable client validation, include MvcFoolproofValidation.js with the standard client validation script files:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MvcFoolproofValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**jQuery Validation**
If you are using jQuery validation, include MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.js with the standard client validation script files:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**MVC 3 jQuery Unobtrusive Support**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If still client side validation not showing check that your drop-down has `input-validation-error` class.
if class is present and not showing red border then add style :

```
.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this, if an error occurred in a validation it would have the class **input-validation-error**. So you can just style that class like:

```
.input-validation-error{
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #ff0000;
}
```

**Or** if you want to be specific to that drop-down you can do a simple trick to like this:
First create a class like **red-border**

```
.red-border {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Then add a viewbag data like **@ViewBag.Test_Type_Border** in your dropdown like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Test_Type, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Test_TypeChoice, new {@class = "form-control " + @ViewBag.Test_Type_Border})
```

Make sure there is a space between the form-control and the ViewBag

Now is your controller, If the model state is not valid check if the dropdown value is empty, and if so set the @ViewBag.Test_Type_Border like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid){
//Your code if model state is valid
}
//if it is not valid then check if the dropdown field is empty
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Test_Type))
{
     //Set the viewbag to the class red-border
     @ViewBag.Test_Type_Border = "red-border";
}
```

Then return to the view, the dropdown would now have a red border